# Kendo Grid. How to display dataTextField in Grid's cell instead of dataValueField?

Tags: php, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want to display Text for my ForigenKey columns instead of numeric values. There are a lot of examples to retrieve TextMember by comparing ID but they are not working in my case. I just started to use Kendo ui so dont know much about it

Here is the code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

 dataSource1 = new kendo.data.DataSource({

        transport: {
              read:  {
               url: "Data/AttendanceCode/GridSelect.php",
                dataType: "json",

                            },

                update: {
                   url: "Data/AttendanceCode/GridUpdate.php",
        dataType: "json",
                        type:"GET"
            },

                  destroy: {
                     url: "Data/AttendanceCode/GridDelete.php",
                      dataType: "json",
          type:"POST"
                            },

                    create: {
                      url: "Data/AttendanceCode/GridInsert.php",
                        dataType: "json",
              type:"POST"
                            },

                        },

                  schema: {
         data: "data",

                       model: {
                          id: "AttendenceID",

                           fields: {
                              AttendenceID : { editable: false, nullable: true },
                              TeacherID: { field: "TeacherID", defaultValue: "EIIT0002" },
                                }
                            }
                        },


                    });



$("#grid").kendoGrid({
           dataSource: dataSource1,

    pageSize: 10,
            pageable: {
                refresh: true,
                pageSizes: true
                    },
                    editable:{ mode : "popup" },
                    height: 400,
        filterable: true,
                    columnMenu: true,
        sortable: true, 
                    reorderable: true,
                    resizable: true,
                    toolbar: ["create"],

                    columns: [
                       { field:"AttendenceID", title: "Attendence ID", width:"130px" },

                       { field: "TeacherID", title:"Teacher", width: "100px" , editor: TeacherDropDownEditor, template: "#=getTeacherName(TeacherID)#" },

                   { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "Action", width: "210px" }],

                });


            });
```

Teacher DropDown DataSource

```
teacher = new kendo.data.DataSource({

       transport: {
         read: {
    url : "Data/Teacher.php",
    dataType: "json" }
               },

    schema: {
    data : "Teacher"
         }

    });
```

// Teacher Editor

```
 function TeacherDropDownEditor(container, options) {
   $('<input data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
.appendTo(container)
     .kendoDropDownList({         
     dataTextField: "TeacherName",
dataValueField: "Service_NO",
 dataSource: teacher
     });
}
```

Different approaches i found and tried to Get Teacher Name

1 -

```
  function getTeacherName(value) {

          var text = "";
     $.each(teacher, function () {
           if (this.Service_NO == value) {
            text = this.Name;
             return false;
           }
        });
     return text;
                      }
```

2 -

```
function getTeacherName(teacherID) {

 for (var idx = 0, length = teacher.length; idx < length; idx++) 
   {
    if (teacher[idx].Service_NO === teacherID) 
       {t = teacher[idx].Name;} 
    }                   
return t; 
    }
```

3 -

```
function getTeacherName(teacherID) {
      $.each(teacher, function(key, val) {
        if(val.Service_NO == tID){
           t = val.Name;
            }
             });
           return t;
            }
```

It seems like dataSource (teacher) is not having any value.
PHP code is working perfectly.
Please Help if you have any idea whats wrong with my code.

Thanks !!

Comment: Code is working. Thanks OnaBai ... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, `teacher` DataSource does not have any data because you are defining how to get the data (that's what you do with the DataSource) but you are not reading it.

Add:

```
teacher.read();
```

for manually forcing the data read.

**NOTE:** This is something that happens *magically* when you have a Grid, ListView,... because these widget do it for you but this time, for displaying your grid you need to read it in advance since it is invoked from a JavaScript function (KendoUI grid code doesn't know anything about what you have in the function `getTeacherName` other than the name).

Answer (score 0):

you should config your field:

```
{ field: "nu_status", title: 'Status', values: [ { text: "Active", value: 1 }, { text: "Inactive", value: 0 }]},
```